Distribute DLLs in Nuget
I am working on a C# library (LLamaSharp) which wraps a C++ library (llama.cpp).
As part of the nuget package we're including DLLs compiled with all the various types of hardware support (CUDA, OpenCL, Vulkan, AVX/AVX2/AVX512 etc). At runtime the best possible backend is selected for the hardware available.
You can see the current folder hierarchy with all of the backends in it here. Automatic selection depends on this exact layout to be able to find the relevant DLLs. The nuspec file used to build the package is here.
However, with the current setup this fails when publishing a "Self Contained" build (in visual studio: Build > Publish, set deployment mode to "self contained"). It will produce this error:
Found multiple publish output files with the same relative path:
 - llamasharp.backend.cpu\0.11.1\runtimes\win-x64\native\avx\llama.dll,
 - llamasharp.backend.cpu\0.11.1\runtimes\win-x64\native\avx2\llama.dll,
 - llamasharp.backend.cpu\0.11.1\runtimes\win-x64\native\avx512\llama.dll,
 - llamasharp.backend.cpu\0.11.1\runtimes\win-x64\native\llama.dll

It seems that the entire folder hierarchy is flattened by the build process. This causes an immediate build error (multiple files going to the same place) and would also cause runtime selection to fail (files are not being placed in the correct folders).
What is the correct way to distribute a folder hierarchy of DLLs through nuget and preserve the structure in the final build?

While you are probably using P/Invoke, I don't see the relevance to this issue.

Probably not relevant, but there's a small chance a pinvoke wizard comes along and tells me this is all easy to do with some built-in magic!

I see your point there. Fair enough.

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues?q=is%3Aissue+runtimes+flatten

Not sure how you run the nuget pack command, and maybe I miss something, but if I clone the repo, get into LLama\runtimes\build directory (replace runtime/deps file src paths by ../deps so it can build) and run nuget pack LLamaSharp.Backend.Cpu.nuspec, it works (minor a  NU5127 warning), it builds a 12M .nupkg file with all native hierarchies in there in a runtime folder.

Problem is if you run a build with that nuget package (Publish, Self Contained) it won't work. You'll get the error about multiple files with the same output path because it's trying to flatten the hierarchy. Try pulling LLamaSharp + LLamaSharp.Backend.CPU into a project and doing a publish build to see the issue for yourself.

Can you specify exactly the steps that get to your problem

I edited a little more detail into the question. You just install the backend package and do Build > Publish with deployment mode set to "self contained". It'll produce that error about multiple files being built to the same path.

The whole solutions builds fine and I can run LLama.Examples but what do you mean by "install the backend package" and there's no profile visible when we do Build > Publish.

Sorry I meant install the packages from nuget into an empty new project. The main llamasharp project works just fine, this is specifically a problem when you use the nuget packages.

Ok now I get it and I reproduce. I think it's a won't fix/by design thing see https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/16211 and https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9643 you can check it with msbuild binlog: https://i.imgur.com/rCaQphH.png all llama.dll don't have a final relative path, it's all flattened. The easy solution is to build multiple packages, one per target (one for cpu avx, one for cpu avx2, and let use choose, etc.). There are other ways, for example embed dlls and write them dynamically, provide a custom msbuild target to resolve conflicts, etc.

To keep DLLs folder in NuGet package, do that >>


Edit .nuspec file. Add DLLs with paths.
Use contentFiles to set paths.


Example:
<files>
  <file src="runtimes\win-x64\native\avx\llama.dll" target="runtimes\win-x64\native\avx\llama.dll" />
  <file src="runtimes\win-x64\native\avx2\llama.dll" target="runtimes\win-x64\native\avx2\llama.dll" />
  <file src="runtimes\win-x64\native\avx512\llama.dll" target="runtimes\win-x64\native\avx512\llama.dll" />
  <file src="runtimes\win-x64\native\llama.dll" target="runtimes\win-x64\native\llama.dll" />
</files>

This way keep folder structure and no flatten problem.

This doesn't answer the question, this is already specified like this in the repository. Read comments.
